# FileUpload iphone c# aspx

Tags: c#, iphone, file-upload

I have FileUpload control on my website but on iphone , control is disabled. I am quite new to iPhone...Can anyone explain how can I add the functionality of ImageUpload on my website, so that user can upload image from iphone gallery.

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Hello aDev, want ImageUpload functionality om iPhone app or website?

Comment: Thanks for reply! on .NET website

Comment: Then you can not do anything from iPhone. Try it with .Net.

Comment: but that I am asking how to do with .NET

Comment: Sorry aDev, I don't know for that. Bcz I am not .Net developer. I am mobile application developer.

Comment: no problem and thanks for reply!..will see if I find something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at all, iOS SDK does not allow uploading of file, dont know about iPad but in iPhone it is disabled. There is only one way to upload file, that is to make an iPhone App and user must install this app on the mobile and you should write code to upload file. There is no simpler way.

Comment: ok, Thanks for reply! but then what about the solution which is posted above.

Comment: That solution is only useful within iPhone OS Application, you can not do anything on your server side programming. You have to make an application and your user must download and install that application before they can upload anything.